# Python - Why is my list not being modified outside the scope of this method? How do I modify my code so that it is?

Tags: python, list, filter, scope

I have the following method:

```
def instances(candidate, candidates):
    count = candidates.count(candidate)

    # Removing candidate from candidates. #
    list(filter(candidate.__ne__, candidates))
    return {candidate: count}
```

Its intended purpose is to find how many instances of a certain element are in a list, delete those instances from the list, and return a  `Key:Value` pair representing the element and its number of instances.

So if I make a list and call the function, it should do the following:

```
>>> someList = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
>>> print(instances(1, someList))
{1: 3}
>>> print(someList)
[2, 3]
```

However, for the last line, I get this instead:

```
>>> print(someList)
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

The line `list(filter(candidate.__ne__, candidates))` returns the correct list that I want, but it seems it exists only in the function's scope. If I modify this line to instead read `candidates = list(filter(candidate.__ne__, candidates))`, for some reason `candidates` is being interpreted as a local variable inside the scope of the function. I can't simply return the list filter because I need to return the `Key:Value` pair for another part of my program.

I find it really strange that `candidates` is interpreted as a local variable in this line, whereas just above it, the reference to `candidates` is interpreted as a parameter of the function.

> Can someone please help me understand why this is happening? And if possible, suggest a solution consistent with the intended purpose? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I find it really strange that candidates is interpreted as a local variable in this line, whereas just above it, the reference to candidates is interpreted as a parameter of the function.

Python [doesn't have references](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/).  It has variables.  `foo = bar` means "make the variable `foo` point at whatever `bar` points at."  Reassigning a variable just re-seats the pointer.  It doesn't let you change the "other" variables which point to a given value.  Parameters are passed using the same method: make a new pointer to the object.  There is thus no direct support for [three star programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Modifying a list in-place is done with slicing syntax.  You could do something like this:

```
candidates[:] = filter(candidate.__ne__, candidates)
```

Comment: You don't even need the `list()` in this case; the slice assignment will take any iterable.

Comment: Thank you! The first url linked is especially helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function to return two results:

```
def instances(candidate, candidates):
    count = candidates.count(candidate)    
    return {candidate: count}, list(filter(candidate.__ne__, candidates))
```

And when you run it, use:

```
someList = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
res, someList = instances(1, someList)
print res
```

As for explanation of why it doesn't work - you can find a detailed one [here](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/), and I'll try to give it a shot myself:

Python is "pass by value" which is pretty straight forward when you discuss passing an `int` or a `str`. That said, it gets a bit more confusing when you're passing "an object" - what you actually pass is a *copy of a reference* to that object.

This means that any changes to the object itself will be visible outside the function - **but** if you try to change the reference itself - it will not be visible. Remember the "copy" part? you did *not* pass the reference but a copy of that reference - so re-assigning a value to that copy of a reference will not be visible!

**Comment**: another (good) option is to "change the object behind the pointer" - as [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30564940/1057429) shows in his answer by using Slicing!

Answer (score 0):

`filter(candidate.__ne__, candidates)` does not modify `candidates`. It returns new iterator. And `list(filter(...))` returns new list.

Try this

```
def instances(candidate, candidates):
count = candidates.count(candidate)

# Removing candidate from candidates.
for i in range(count)
    candidates.remove(candidate)
return {candidate: count}
```

Answer (score 0):

`list(filter(candidate.__ne__, candidates))` (specifically `filter`) doesn't modify the list `candidates` in place, it just returns a new *filtered* list which is different from `candidates`.

In your case, I would suggest the following:

```
while True:
    try:
        candidates.remove(candidate)
    except ValueError:  
        # If there's no more candidate in candidates
        # ValueError will be raised, in this case, we can stop removing
        break
```